# Rspec NoMethodError: undefined method `errors_on'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I'm testing for validation of entry of a city attribute in an addresses model. My model spec is as follows

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Address, :type => :model do
  before(:each) do
    @valid_attributes = {
      street: 'rock avenue',
      city: 'MSA',
      zip: '00100',
      person_id: 1
    } # runs before each it block
  end

  context "Validations" do
    it 'must have a city' do
      a = Address.new
      expect(a.errors_on(:city)).not_to be_empty
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the spec, i get the following error

```
  1) Address Validations must have a city
     Failure/Error: expect(a.errors_on(:city)).not_to be_empty
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `errors_on' for #<Address:0xd844538>
     # ./spec/models/address_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My test gems are set up as following in my Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'libnotify'
  gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
end
```

I have included the rspec collection matchers in my spec_helper, so I don't understand why I am getting this error

My **spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'capybara/rspec' 
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'rspec/collection_matchers'
```

However I can see that the method, **errors_on** has been defined in rspec-collection_matchers gem as shown [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers/blob/master/lib/rspec/collection_matchers/rails_extensions.rb)

My **.rspec**

```
--color
--require spec_helper
```

I have also changed the position of

```
require 'rspec/collection_matchers'
```

to **rails_helper.rb**, but running the test suite again brings up the same error

**rails_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'rspec/collection_matchers'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

My **spec_helper.rb** is empty with only the block below:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
end
```

I am using Rails 4.1.0, rspec 3.0.0 and rspec-collection_matchers 1.0.0

Comment: Your spec requires `rails_helper`, but you put the `require 'rspec/collection_matchers'` line in `spec_helper` -- Does your `rails_helper` file require 'spec_helper'?

Comment: @DylanMarkow yes, my rails_helper.rb file requires spec_helper

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the repo, this is only a guess based on the information. I think this is a load order problem.

It looks like you are loading `rspec/collection_matchers` in `spec_helper`, not `rails_helper`. If you are using the new default configuration, `--require spec_helper` is in your `.rspec` file. When you run rspec this will require `spec_helper` very early on. When that happens it requires `rspec/collection_matchers`. However, at that point `rails_helper` has not been loaded. Unfortunately, this also means most of `ActiveSupport` including `ActiveModel` are not loaded yet. It also means the Rails autoloading functionality has not been loaded, so those won't get defined when you reference them.

All this to say, the check for `ActiveModel` [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers/blob/master/lib/rspec/collection_matchers/rails_extensions.rb#L1) returns `false`. Which does not load `errors_on`.

Try moving the require into `rails_helper`.

**Note on testing in isolation:**

If you are going for faster testing in isolation this is my suggestion:

- `spec_helper` should be kept very minimal and lightweight, that means for the most part you shouldn't add any `require` declarations to it
- Move the requires you listed from `spec_helper` into `rails_helper`, those are mostly Rails specific and do not belong in `spec_helper` as Rails is not loaded there
- If you need access to the other `rspec/collection_matchers` functionality in specs which do not require Rails, then just add the `require 'rspec/collection_matchers'` to the top of the spec file; Ruby will handle making sure it is only loaded once

Comment: I have moved everything require to the rails_helper, as you suggested, but I still get the error

Comment: I have also included the rails_helper and spec_helper file contents on my question

Comment: It's the same problem. You are requiring the collection matchers before you load rails. Move the requires until after you `require 'rspec/rails'`